# using rm -rf in the scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, rm

sometimes using `rm -rf` in script could be catastrophic

example

```
rm -rf $TMP/$folder
```

when TMP and $folder are without any value , it will actually

removing all under "/"

so I am asking how to use the `rm -rf` in the scripts so it will be safe?

Comment: Prepending any removal operation with a check for the existence of whatever you want the script to delete would be a good start. Not using `rm -r` with `-f`is also a good idea.

Comment: $folder is always with sub folders and files

Comment: Then you have the script query the system about the existence of `$TMP/$folder` before deleting `$folder`  and have it abort/skip the deletion if `$TMP/$folder` isn't there.

Comment: @Mioriin That doesn't solve the problem, because if both variables are empty (as per the question), then `/` will still exist.

Comment: @yael Can't you just check for non-empty variables as well before running the command?

Comment: In addition to checking for non-empty variables, run `du` to verify that the target directory is not larger than you expect.

Comment: Tip one: use quotes. Tip two: prepend with `/` or `./`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if `$TMP` and `$TMP/$folder` are directories
2. Check that the canonical paths of `$TMP` and `$TMP/$folder` are different (imagine `folder=""` or `folder="/"`)
3. Check if `$TMP/$folder` is writable

```
if [ -d "$TMP" ]\
 && [ -d "$TMP/$folder" ]\
 && [ "$(readlink -e "$TMP")" != "$(readlink -e "$TMP/$folder")" ]\
 && [ -w "$TMP/$folder" ]; then
    rm -rf "$TMP/$folder"
else
    echo "Could not delete folder \"$TMP/$folder\", TMP=$TMP, folder=$folder" >&2
fi
```